# Cancel pull right when the content goes to the new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<footer id="footer" class="bg-dark pt10">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <span class="copyright link">Copyright © 2006-2015 Pure International</span>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/privacy"); ?>"><?= lang("privacy"); ?></a></li>|
                        <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/terms"); ?>"><?= lang("t&c"); ?></a></li>|
                        <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/about_us"); ?>"><?= lang("about_us"); ?></a></li>|
                        <li><a class="link" href="<?= site_url("page/view/contact_us"); ?>"><?= lang("contact_us"); ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

The output is like that:

```
AAAAA          BB|CC|DD|EE
```

It works fine on large screen, however, when the screen is smaller, the right content goes to a new line:

```
AAAAA
              BB|CC|DD|EE
```

And aligns to right.

How can I prevent that? What I would like to achieve is:

```
AAAAA
BB|CC|DD|EE
```

When the screen becomes smaller. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `pull-left` with `text-align: right;`.

**Snippet**

```css
.pull-left {float: left; width: 50%;}
.text-right {text-align: right;}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .pull-left {float: none;}
  .text-right {text-align: left;}
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-left">Left</div>
<div class="pull-left text-right">Right</div>
```